# Get android.os.Handler message callback in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-recomposition

I want the callbacks for the handler message callback event in the compose.

I am using the produceState but sometimes its not getting values properly

Suggest me the best approach to use this methods in compose

```
produceState(initialValue = 0) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) { msg ->
            value = msg.what
            false
        }
    }
```

Please help me thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using Handler and Looper directly within produceState in Jetpack Compose for message callbacks is not the most idiomatic approach, especially considering Compose's emphasis on state and recomposition. There are better ways to handle asynchronous updates in Compose, typically using State and CoroutineScope.

Let me suggest a more Compose-friendly approach using LaunchedEffect and CoroutineScope. If you are trying to listen for some asynchronous events and reflect their results in your Compose UI, you can use a MutableState variable and update it in a coroutine:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
val myState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) { msg ->
        myState.value = msg.what
        false
    }

    // Set up your message sending logic or listener that uses this handler
    // For example, someExternalClass.setHandler(handler)
  }

// Use myState.value in your UI
Text("Current value: ${myState.value}")
}
```

In this example:

1. LaunchedEffect is used to initialize the handler. The LaunchedEffect block will run when the composable enters the composition and will not rerun unless its key (Unit in this case) changes. This is a good place to initialize handlers or listeners.
2. myState is a MutableState variable that holds the current state.
   When the handler receives a message, it updates myState.
3. The UI reacts to changes in myState and recomposes accordingly.

This approach is more in line with the reactive nature of Jetpack Compose.
It ensures that your composables will recompose and update the UI when the state changes. However, remember that using Handler and Looper is more typical for traditional Android development, and in many cases, there might be more modern approaches available, especially if working with Kotlin Coroutines or Flows.

Ensure that you clean up (e.g., remove callbacks or listeners) in cases where your composable leaves the composition to avoid memory leaks or unwanted behavior.
This can be done in the LaunchedEffect block by adding a cleanup action in the form of a lambda that is returned at the end of the block.